# help with manipulation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let X & Y be two independent random variables. I was wondering if someone could clarify the manipulation of this conditional expectation.

1. if E(XY|X) = E(X(Y|X))
2. if E(XY|X) = XE(Y|X)

Are either of these correct?

Comment: Do you have a source for this expression? Too me sorry it doesn't make sense (1) XY|X doesn't make sense since X can't be a random variable, and a given conditional at the same time (can't be on LHS and RHS of vertical bar). (2) The expression X(Y|X) doesn't make sense to me for similar reasons, I'm not sure how X can be a function and a conditional variable at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @tisPrimeTime, It is okay for a random variable to be on both sides of the bar. $\mathsf E(XY\mid X)$ is *the expected value of the product, $X$ times $Y$, when given $X$*.  This is quite sensible.  It is clearly equal to *$X$ times the expected value of $Y$ given $X$.* That is $X~\mathsf E(Y\mid X)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ahhh you are correct! Good catch, I suppose the implication here is that the expectation must be taken w.r.t. $Y$ no? Even though it is not written explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is correct. The first one does not make sense as it is. You probably meant $E(XY|X)=E(XE(Y|X))$. This is false. LHS is $XEY$ and RHS is $(EX)(EY)$